# Best stack for unit testing backbone apps

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jenkins

With so many testing frameworks to choose from, and taking into consideration that continuous integration with Jenkins is a must, which would currently be the best/least-complex stack for unit testing a Backbone app?